# Needed assistance with the spotify web api

Tags: web, spotify

so I wanted to know if it was possible to get the top playlists, then the user playlist etc. using the spotify web api or is it just possible using libspotify?

Answer (score 0):

The Web API currently has no playlist functionality at all.

Comment: Thanks for that, also what about the pyspotify python lib?

Comment: You'd have to consult their documentation.

Comment: So my plan is to use the spotify API for creating a mobile app. So even by some miracle I get the playlists, wont the user of the mobile app need a premium acct to access the content in my app which I have got from spotify.